# TYPO3 Extbase Model n:1 Bidirectional

Tags: model, typo3, many-to-one, extbase, bidirectional

I have following Model:

```
 FilePackage
      - ID
      - Name

 FileGroup
      - ID
      - Name
      - filePackage              

 File
      - ID 
      - Path   
      - fileGroup
```

If i want to get all files for a Group i currently make some queries like.

```
$groups = $this->fileGroupRepository->findByPackage($package);
foreach($groups as $group){
     $files = $this->fileRepository->findByFilegroup($group);
     foreach($files as $file){
         // Handle it...
     }
}
```

Is it possible to access those directly? Like 
    $groups = $this->fileGroupRepository->findByPackage($package);
    foreach($groups as $group){
         $group->getFiles();
    }

Without query everything before and to directly use it in the templates

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the configuration in your TCA Extbase should take care of getting all related objects.

For example:

**Filegroup**

```
'files' => array(
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:foo_myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xml:tx_foomyext_domain_model_filegroup.files',
    'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'group',
        'internal_type' => 'db',
        'allowed' => 'tx_foomyext_domain_model_file',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_foomyext_domain_model_file',
        'MM' => 'tx_foomyext_filegoup_file_mm',
        'maxitems'      => 10,
        'minitems'      => 0,
        'size'      => 10,
    ),
),
```

**File**

```
'filegroups' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:tw_foomyext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xml:tx_foomyext_domain_model_file.filegroups',
    'config'  => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_foomyext_domain_model_filegroup',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY tx_foomyext_domain_model_filegroup.id',
        'MM' => 'tx_foomyext_filegroup_file_mm',
        'MM_opposite_field' => 'files',
        'size' => 5,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 10,
    )
),
```

In your Model these properties should be represented as ObjectStorage.

If you then select a filegroup Extbase will automatically get all related files for you and you will have access to them.